# Instantiating class so public properties are available for all event handlers in page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Without using Session variables or static classes, is it possible to instantiate a class that's available to all the event handlers in one webform?

For example, my code looks like this. I instantiate Car and set `property` Color in `Page_Load`. I know I can't access it from another event handler.

I prefer not using session variables since they tend to expire, and the users here tend to go to a page and then leave it open for a while. I could always set the session's timeout, but I prefer something that lasts throughout the page's life cycle.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class ToErase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Car myCar = new Car();
            myCar.Color = "Black";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Have access to myCar.Color here;
            //Response.Write(myCar.Color);
        }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it as below and then you would be able to access it :-

```
 public partial class ToErase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Car myCar;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.myCar = new Car();
            this.myCar.Color = "Black";
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.myCar.Color = "Blue"; ////You can access it here
            //Have access to myCar.Color here;
            Response.Write(this.myCar.Color);
        }
    }
    public class Car
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about *persistence* then in WebForms, `ViewState` comes to mind (for above).

Depending on use case, at the end of the day, you *could* involve the client more, with client-based persistence (e.g. DOM storage, etc.). At the end of the day, *events* like `click` occur on the client-side...ASP.Net sort of abstracts much of that for you. If you checked the source of your WebForms page, you'll see all that Javascript that does the "magic" for you.

Hth...

Comment: In terms of persistence, would there be a difference between a class instance and viewstate?

Answer (score 0):

Am i missing someting ? Just with

```
public partial class ToErase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Car myCar;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {....}

}
```